# LM748 uses positive rail as an input on a 1980's UK sound effect generator. Is this an old trick that I've never seen?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, sound, music

[image: old sound effects schematic]

TP9 is a +/-15V signal from a VCO.

The signal to the base of Q7 is 0 - 10V from another card that is presumed to be basically DC.

The multiplier AR11 has a sound coming from an LFSR circuit on another page. It sounds just like the race car from an Atari 2600 console.

There is a power schedule on another page that is showing AR8 pin 7 missing from the +15V rail.

Any way that I try to simulate this, I get a small AC signal down at the negative rail. When that signal hits the multiplier, all that I get is nonsense out (-15V * the sound). I can see no DC blocking in this schematic at all.

I'm posting this here in desperation to see if someone knows of some 1980's op-amp trick that might be in play here that I'm missing.

I'm using a modern op-amp in the sim because that's what I have. I just used some diodes to clamp the input because that's what I believe they would have done in the older version. The design simulates the same with different input configurations of AR8.

[image: LTSpice]

[image]

Comment: I've not used the power rails of an opamp for inputs. But I have used them to create bipolar outputs.

Answer (score 2):

There's apparently no feedback around the uncompensated op-amp so looks like they're using it as a comparator, and it originally was suggested for such use (image from NS datasheet [here](https://studylib.net/doc/18515217/lm748-operational-amplifier)):

[image]

They can change the amplitude of the output by changing the positive rail voltage with the pot R94 and emitter follower buffer Q7.

There's not enough schematic supplied to see exactly what's going on, but that fits with what is there. LM748 is a bipolar part and I would not expect any internal parasitic diodes to the positive rail.

Many modern op-amps are ill suited for use as comparators. As well as slow speed due to the internal compensation and saturation recovery time, they can have protection diodes to the rails or protection structures between the input pins that can draw relatively high current when the differential input voltage is not low.